# Show progress of Haskell program

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have list in Haskell with some objects. And I need to find out whether someone of these objects satisfied certain condition. So, I wrote the following:

```
any (\x -> check x) xs
```

But the problem is that check operation is very expensive, and the list is quite big. I want to see current progress in runtime, for example `50% (1000/2000 checked).`
How I can do this?

Comment: If you are doing some heavy lifting with large data set, don't use List. List are good for learning but perform badly in real world app

Comment: Also, any will return as soon as it finds an element that match the condition, in that case the progress of showing how much elements from total elements are processed doesn't make sense

Comment: @Ankur it makes sense, why not? It can be interpreted as '30% of elements have been processed and nothing suitable have been found'

Comment: I meant generally when you show a progress, user expect it to go till 100% rather than abruptly exit at, let's say 10%. But it can be fine if this is just for you to test something this way

Comment: @Ankur, it's just for me, yes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you want to see the progress of your function (which is a side effect of the function) the most obvious solution is to use monads. So the first thing to do is to make a monadic version of the `any` function:

```
anyM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m Bool
anyM _ []        = return False
anyM pred (x:xs) = reduce (pred x) xs
    where reduce acc []     = acc
          reduce acc (x:xs) = do
              condition <- acc
              if condition
                  then return condition
                  else reduce (pred x) xs
```

The above function `anyM` is a monadic version of the `any` function. It allows us to produce side effects in addition to checking whether any item in the given list satisfies the given predicate.

We can use the `anyM` function to create another function which displays a progress bar as a side effect in addition to executing the `any` function as follows:

```
anyVar :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> IO Bool
anyVar pred xs = anyM check $ zip [1..] xs
    where check (n,x) = do
            putStrLn $ show n ++ " checked. "
            return $ pred x
```

Notice that since we don't know the length of the list beforehand we only display the number of items in the list checked. If we know the number of items in the list beforehand then we can display a more informative progress bar:

```
anyFix :: (a -> Bool) -> Int -> [a] -> IO Bool
anyFix pred length xs = anyM check $ zip [1..] xs
    where check (n,x) = do
            putStrLn $ show (100 * n `div` length) ++ "% (" ++
                show n ++ "/" ++ show length ++ " checked). "
            return $ pred x
```

Use the `anyVar` function for infinite lists and for lists whose length you don't know beforehand. Use the `anyFix` function for finite lists whose length you do know beforehand.

If the list is big and you don't know the length of the list beforehand then the `length` function will need to traverse the entire list to determine its length. Hence it would be better to use `anyVar` instead.

Finally to wrap it all this is how you would use the above functions:

```
main = anyFix (==2000) 2000 [1..2000]
```

In your case you could do the following instead:

```
main = anyVar check xs
```

Hope this answer helped you.

Comment: Excellent answer but your anyM does its check twice for every element which is bad for two reasons : first if the check is expensive we don't want to double our amount of work, second since it is monadic, it could notice it's called twice, for instance a State used to track how many elements were handled would be confused. Better replace your if by `if condition then return condition else reduce (pred x) xs`.

Comment: @Jedai Nice catch. I never noticed it before. Perhaps because `"\ESC[2K\ESC[0G"` erased the line every time. I'm confused though - why does it execute twice? An explanation would be great. In addition for some reason my `anyVar` and `anyFix` functions raise a parse error on `putStr`. However if I replace the `do` block with `putStr "string" >> return (pred x)` then it works as expected. Would you happen to know why this occurs?

Comment: @Jedai I figured out why `anyVar` and `anyFix` were raising a parse error: it was due to incorrect indentation. I'm still wondering why my original `anyM` function evaluated `pred` twice for every item.

Answer (score 12):

Another way of doing this is using a streaming library like `conduit` or `pipes`. Here is some sample code using [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.0), which prints a dot every time an element of the list arrives to be checked:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P 

bigList :: [Int]
bigList = [1,2,3,4]

check :: Int -> Bool
check = (>3)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <- P.any check $ each bigList >-> P.chain (\_ -> putStrLn ".")
    putStrLn . show $ result
```

([each](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.0/docs/Pipes.html#v%3aeach) is a function from the Pipes module.)

Now, if you wanted to show percentages, the `P.chain (\_ -> putStrLn ".")` part of the pipeline would have to be a bit smarter. It would have to carry the current percentage as state, and know the lenght of the list. (If your list is enormous and lazily generated, calculating its length would force its evaluation and possibly cause problems. If you already have it in memory, it wouldn't be much of a problem.)

**Edit:** here is an possible extension of the previous code that actually shows percentages:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import Data.Function
import Control.Monad.RWS

bigList :: [Int]
bigList = [1,2,3,4]

check :: Int -> Bool
check = (>3)

-- List length is the environment, number of received tasks is the state. 
tracker :: (MonadReader Int m, MonadState Int m, MonadIO m) => Pipe a a m r
tracker = P.chain $ \_ -> do
    progress <- on (/) fromIntegral `liftM` (modify succ >> get) `ap` ask
    liftIO . putStrLn . show $ progress

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (result,()) <- evalRWST (P.any check $ each bigList >-> tracker)
                            (length bigList) -- list length as unchanging environment
                            0 -- initial number of received tasks (the mutable state)
    putStrLn . show $ result
```

It could be further refined to show only significant percentage increases.

Comment: I know length of the list, so it's not a problem.

Comment: If you know the length, an Array would seem to be a better choice than a List.

Answer (score 7):

The most naive and direct way is to implement your own

```
anyM :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> IO Bool
```

that prints the progress bar (e.g. using [terminal-progress-bar](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/terminal-progress-bar)).

But note that in order to calculate a percentage, you will have to evaluate the full list. This breaks lazyness and can have bad and unwanted effects on the space behaviour of the program.

There are also approaches using `unsafePerformIO` and `unsafeInterleaveIO` that allows you to monitor a pure calculation (such as `any`), see [bytestring-progress](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-progress) for an example. But this is dubious design that you should only use if you know that you understand the consequences.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use `Debug.Trace.trace` and keep track of current position like so:

```
any (\(i,x) -> trace (showProgress i (length xs)) $ check x) $ zip [1..] xs
```

Comment: `trace` is a hack that relies on `unsafePerformIO`. As the module name suggests this is only intended for debugging. Never use it for production code!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a library for explicit exceptions, like `explicit-exception:Control.Monad.Execption.Synchronous` or `transformers:Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe` and "throw an exception" when you found an element that passes the check.